# Different custom Gradle plugins are treated as the same

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have some common Gradle convention script plugins living in their own git repository. These are published to a nexus repository and all share the same group. For the sake of visualisation, this is how they look like:

- `com-mycorp.this-conventions.gradle.kts`
- `com-mycorp.that-conventions.gradle.kts`

On the nexus repository they can be found under:

```
com-mycorp/
├─ this-conventions.gradle.kts/
│  ├─ com-mycorp.this.conventions.gradle.kts/
│  │  ├─ 0.0.1 
├─ that-conventions.gradle.kts/
│  ├─ com-mycorp.that.conventions.gradle.kts/
│  │  ├─ 0.0.1
```

The problem occurs when applying these plugins in my multi-module Gradle project.

For my own reasons, I need to apply **one** of these plugins at the root level (to be shared by all submodules) and **the other** only in on submodule. So this is how it looks like:

**(root) build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
  id("com-mycorp.this-conventions") version "0.0.1" apply false
}

subprojects {
  apply(plugin = "com-mycorp.this-conventions")
}
```

**(submodule) build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
  id("com-mycorp.that-conventions") version "0.0.1" // doesn't work with version
}
```

As described in the comment, this doesn't work if I put the version there. I'm getting a message indicating that the plugin "is already on the classpath and must not include a version". But this makes no sense, because these are two different plugins but it seems they are somehow treated as the same. This works if I remove the version but I'm having trouble decoding why. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the output from Gradle that you are getting?

Comment: Also, do you already have these as dependencies in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`, that is one way that you would get an error about including the version. If that is the case, just remove the version as it says.